# POST/get JSON using Ararat Synapse with special PEM key (Lazarus/FPC)

Tags: json, rest, freepascal, lazarus, ararat-synapse

We are forced to send (and receive back) JSON data to the government from our restaurant program

- using a special RSA Key (PEM stream) they provide
- using TLS 1.3 (OpenSSL 3.0+) < This works! :-)

The only way I found is to create a separate DLL for that under Lazarus, which can use a separate component to do that, *(and load that special key, so it does not interfere with the main program's Indy component.)*

Ararat Synapse's new [Trunk](https://sourceforge.net/p/synalist/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/) (R260) can handle OpenSSL 3.0, so I've downloaded and installed as component, but the JSON I'm sending to a test server (webhook.com) are distorted krix-krax.

## How do I load a special .PEM key/stream **(not a file!)** for the SSL communication before sending it?

Here is my code:

```pascal
function HttpPostGetJSON(const URL: string; var JSON: UTF8String; const key, pem: string; const TimeOut: integer = 5000): Boolean;
var
    HTTP    : THTTPSend;
    Data    : TStringStream;
begin
    HTTP := THTTPSend.Create;
    Data := TStringStream.Create(JSON, TEncoding.UTF8);
    JSON := '';
    HTTP.Timeout := TimeOut;           

    try
        HTTP.Headers.Add('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8') ;
        HTTP.Headers.Add('Accept: application/json') ;

        // TODO: specify PEM key for the SSL !

        Data.Position := 0;
        HTTP.Document.CopyFrom( Data, 0); 
        Data.Size := 0;

        Result := HTTP.HTTPMethod('POST', URL);
        if Result then begin
            if HTTP.Document.Size > 0 then begin
                Data.LoadFromStream( HTTP.Document );
                JSON := Data.UnicodeDataString;  
            end;
        end;
    finally
        HTTP.Free;
        Data.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: I think the solution will be: `HTTP.Sock.SSL.Certificate := '...' ; ` and `...SSL.PrivateKey:= '...';` but first I have to get that PEM file from the government to test it.

Comment: Well, it does not work this way. If I set both CER + KEY like this: `HTTP.Sock.SSL.Certificate := '-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----'#10+'MIIG...'` I get from `TSSLOpenSSL(HTTP.Sock.SSL).LastErrorDesc` this: `error:068000A8:asn1 encoding routines::wrong tag` .